# Consumir webservice, problema con datetime

Tags: python, webservice, soap, wsdl, zeep

Tengo este codigo para consumir un webservice

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import zeep
import datetime
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep import xsd
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pytz


url = 'https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl?'
client = Client(wsdl=url )
doc = 'Hello World'.encode()

#obtener fecha y hora actual / convertir en format datetime
formato='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.523Z'
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Bogota')
created = datetime.now(tz)
print (created)
print (type(created))


header = zeep.xsd.Element(
        'Security',
        zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
            zeep.xsd.Element(
                'UsernameToken',
                zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                    zeep.xsd.Element('Username',zeep.xsd.String()),
                    zeep.xsd.Element('Password',zeep.xsd.String()),
                    zeep.xsd.Element('Nonce',zeep.xsd.String()),
                    zeep.xsd.Element('Created',zeep.xsd.String()),

                ])
            ),
        ])
    )

factory = client.type_factory('ns0')
data = factory.EnvioFacturaElectronica()
data.NIT = "901193767"
data.InvoiceNumber = "9011937670"
data.IssueDate = created
data.Document = doc
print (data)
print (data.IssueDate)
print (type(data.IssueDate))

header_value = header(UsernameToken={'Username':'fd0653b3-6dd0-45cd-b2f6-bb108ac83a3a','Password':'6361b7b5322acb07ced00a35a85a4cc5183da3a42ede0b07f578067a18425a55', 'Nonce':'pHgdgwGne5Jw+yHy6SdcyQ==','Created':created})
node = client.service.EnvioFacturaElectronica(
                            _soapheaders=[header_value], *data
                            )
```

**Al ejecutar el script obtengo el siguiente error:**

```
TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str
```

Alguien por favor que ejecute el script y me resalte cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

A mi me salio el mismo error cuando corri tu script.
Busque en google, y es un "open issue" en "zeep".
Aqui le link(en ingles) acerca del "bug" en "zeep"

https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/601

Sugerencia: encuentra otro paquete en vez de ZEEP.
Aqui algunas alternativas : 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices

Suerte, R6